# Automatically Generating Controls From Data Connection In Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, data-connections

I vaguely remember in my ASP.NET days a way to drag and drop something like a data connection onto the page to automatically generate controls. I would grab SQLDataConnection1 (or something) that was set to pull back Name, Address and Phone from the Customer table, drop the control or something on the page and it would create textbox controls onto the page for Name, Address and Phone.

This was a long time ago. Is this possible in Windows Forms? Can anyone expand on this concept to let me know the proper sequence, please?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to look in the Data Source tab and look at your data sources.

[image]

Highlighting the field from the data source will reveal a drop down that you can use to change the control type.

[image]

Choose the control type you want and then drag the field to the form and drop it.

[image]

The control and a label are added.